# Deflate zlib vs. Gzip compression on apache ... how to enable

Tags: apache, gzip, deflate, mod-deflate

I've read on a couple of blogs, notably here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/youre-reading-the-worlds-most-dangerous-programming-blog.html there are some advantages to using deflate zlib compression by comparisson to gzip one.

I am trying to setup apache to only do deflate so I can run some tests.
However, I am having difficulty finding to configure mod_deflate to only do deflate and not gzip.

Does anyone know the write configuration parameters.

-- Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. [Apache2's mod_deflate (confusingly) only supports the gzip format](http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/).

Answer (score 1):

As demonkoryu said, mod_deflate supports only the gzip format.

[Deflate compression browser compatibility and advantages over GZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574168/deflate-compression-browser-compatibility-and-advantages-over-gzip)

In the above discussion with links about the disadvantages on using deflate instead of gzip, it looks like you should be worried in particular about browser support: http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/results