# Reduce jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to reduce jQuery to functions that I need.

In this case, I only want to use getJSON with the callback function.  I don't need anything else of jQuery.  Is there any way to cut this out?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: jQuery is open source. You could attempt to strip out that function from a non-compressed build, but you'd likely be in for a lot of pain.

Comment: Are you building a component?  I ask because the file is 31k; it is served from a CDN and the client most likely already has it cached.

Comment: If you are using Webpack you can use my solution to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224584/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do AJAX without jQuery.  One explanation:
http://davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:easy_ajax:txt

Comment: What about allowing cross-domain support?

Comment: JSON is cross-domain, AFAICT.

Comment: JSON is not inherently cross-domain, although you can implement ways to use JSON cross-domain. Have a search for JSON-P to learn more than you'll ever need to know!

Comment: is there a tutorial with ajax / jquery / with jsonp support?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, there are a lot of dependencies, but modularity is planned.

As an aside, a `getJSON()` function isn't particularly hard to implement.