# How to import specific modules from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

If I'm using webpack or browserify, what's the exact process to be able to import only the necessary modules from jQuery that are listed [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules)?

```
import {core, dimensions} from 'jquery'
```

doesn't work.

Comment: I've posted an answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733879/how-can-i-reduce-jquery/68224584#68224584

Answer (score 0):

You can import modules from jQuery's src directory, like so:

```
import core from 'jquery/src/core';
import dimensions from 'jquery/src/dimensions';
```

The jQuery sources use asynchronous module definitions to load modules internally (AMD), so you have to use a module bundler to use it. [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) would be a good choice for this, it supports AMD out of the box.

Comment: My output bundle is larger when I import a couple of modules on their own, rather than when just doing import $ from 'jquery' ....