# What's a queryString doing in this stylesheet's href?

Tags: css

Browsing the boilerplate code at http://html5boilerplate.com/ I'm puzzled at this usage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does appending "?v=1" to CSS and Javascript URLs in link and script tags do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To force update if it is already in browser cache.
the v is probably short for version.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on [Simon's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929064/whats-a-querystring-doing-in-this-stylesheets-href/3929073#3929073)...

Often to conserve bandwidth, stylesheets (amongst other site assets) send headers to the browser that say they should expire a long time from now (often a year). They also send the 304 not modified header.

This is great, but what if someone wants to update the stylesheet? If it was requested as `style.css`, and subsequent requests were to `style.css`, the end user would never redownload it (not for a year anyway).

To combat this, you can append a query string that changes when the file does. For example, it can be easily done in PHP

```
<?php
    $file = 'style.css';
?>

<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file . '?v=' . filemtime($file); ?>" />
```

Now, when the file is updated, the query string changes and the file is redownloaded to all end users. It will not be downloaded again until (a) the expiry time is up or (b) the query string changes again.