# What the heck is this: background-image: url("/images/sprites.png?v=3");

Tags: css, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a queryString doing in this stylesheet's href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929064/whats-a-querystring-doing-in-this-stylesheets-href)

Can someone explain the significance and function of the 1) query string and 2) specific name/value pair (e.g. **?v=3**) in the css snippet please?

```
/*Here is the snippet:*/
    .css-class {
       background-image: url("/images/sprites.png?v=3");
    }
```

I've seen this used on link tags also on http://html5boilerplate.com/:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">
```

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/whats-the-best-way-to-version-css-and-js-urls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely that the URL routes to a static resource on the server, and that the query string is simply a cache-busting modification of the URL. After rolling out a new version of the website's UI, they wanted to make sure none of the old versions of any images were cached on client's machines.

Another common approach is to append a timestamp, which would cause the resource to *never* be cached.

Answer (score 1):

The query string helps to invalidate the browser cache when the image itself is changed.
Context: Usually you want to define long cache expiration date for static resources such as an image, so that browser don't download the image every time they visit the website. However, if the website owner wants to change the image he would need to wait a long time, until the image expires in all of the visitor's browser caches. 
Since he has the query string attached, the website owner can increment the number, when the image has been changed. When the new css file is uploaded, all visitors will see the new image, because it is referenced through a new URL that has not been cached yet.

Answer (score 0):

Found this URL on the HTML5 boilerplate site you linked.  http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Version-Control-with-Cachebusting/

Answer (score 0):

It's like version. WHen there is a new version, owners want you to use new updated one, not one from cache, so `?v` is changed and CSS is redownloaded

Comment: You answered a question which you voted to close - This is why I downvoted.

Comment: The fact it's duplicate doesn't mean it does not deserve answer

Comment: Then why close it so that the asker cant get answers from others which they may find useful?

Comment: there were 6 answers - that's a lot enough. It's poor to downvote me just because you think I downvoted your post

Comment: is a bit (insert word) to say thats why I did it when I gave an explanation above. you stated you wanted to give an answer, because it deserved one, but then closed the question which in fact means that even though there were 6 answers, you didn't leave the scope for someone else to give a productive answer.

Comment: @RyanMurphy: it's about speed here on SO if you didn't spot so

Comment: @Ryan You are welcome to downvote for any reason, but in this case genesis has done nothing wrong, and you are being quite petty.

Answer (score 0):

The URL could refer to a web server that directs the request to a script (e.g. using apache's mod_rewrite), but more likely, the query string is used to make the URL different from a previous version without modifying the actual location, thereby causing browser caches to see it as a different image.