# Is parameter passing in CSS this way a thing?

Tags: css

There is going to be an update for a game, game that's prone to doing ARG's (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_Reality_Game).

In the teaser page, there was a CSS stylesheet, linked as

```
http://www.teamfortress.com/countdown/suspense.css?x=z
```

I've never seen parameters added to a CSS this way (or is it something else?).

I'm talking about the `?x=z`.

If it has no real use, and is just a clue, it could make sense on other things.

Comment: It could be due to css version - when you update the css and browsers have cached the old css ?x=z then you simply change ?x=y - which is new file and browser downloads it.

Comment: You can have the server parse the query string and return different CSS if you like.

Comment: @user3714582 Although, that's usually frowned upon by validation services like PageSpeed Insights, because proxies may not like it.

Comment: The .css extension could be mapped to something server-side which returns a CSS file rather than being a static CSS file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a queryString doing in this stylesheet's href?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929064/whats-a-querystring-doing-in-this-stylesheets-href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has no parameters in it so you cant pass parameters into the CSS file anyway.
This might be a random string to prevent the caching mechanism. When the browser see the filename and the file already cached in your local machine he might decide not to fetch it again. This will keep the old style of the page. A developer can try to out smart the browser by adding a random string at the end, which make the browser think it's a different file than the one he cached.

Another option is URL rewriting. You can map any file extension to a server side script.
The script can create a custom CSS file according to the `GET` parameter.