# What does ?v=2 mean in css?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does appending “?v=1” to CSS and Javascript URLs in link and script tags do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do)

When I download a files from http://html5boilerplate.com/, it has ?v=2 in css.

What does it mean and how does it affect to loading css?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">
```

Comment: Could be anything, it is not related to CSS. It is just a GET parameter. To know what this means would require having insight on the server side. So the only thing we can do is guess (although some scenarios are more likely than others).

Comment: Could we link the dup thread?

Comment: is it clear....enough , we use the version no in our websites,let me know if you need..more details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set caches to expire far in the future adding ?v=2 will let the server know this is a new file but you won't need to give it a unique name ( saving you a global search and replace)

Comment: I assume you are referring to the ability of adding a query string (possibly random) to a file to ensure that it does not cache?  Is that what is happening on this particular website?

Comment: +1 for explaining it way better than i did

Comment: Yep. it used to be in the comments for the boilerplate but it must have been removed in this version

Answer (score 3):

The query string is passed to the webserver, like you would with a script.  I imagine the CSS file referenced is not actually a CSS file, but a script that serves a dynamic version.

The URL is no doubt rewritten to a script which uses the variable v (probably standing for version) to know which CSS variant to supply.

Comment: +1 exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: @casablanca Well you have been saying things all day that I've just been about to say. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Its mainly used to takes care of browser cache.

If your website has that version no and if tomorrow you change the javascript and deploy new file you can update the version no from 2 to 3.

Then browser instead of loading from cache, it loads from server. So that end users won't see the old javascript file.

This is one of main uses of giving version no.

Answer (score 0):

v2 = version 2, when using version control. it shouldn't affect the actual css iside the file at all.