# How to implement a version of css?

Tags: css

Sometimes I notice a thing like:

```
../style.css?v=1.0
```

How to do this? LESS or PHP?

I want to display different content .css file depending on the version

Comment: That's not a version of CSS - it's a way to stop the browser from caching the CSS

Comment: Go through this,this is used for cache for browsers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234235/what-does-v-2-mean-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually GET-parameter for css and js is added in order to be able to update the cached file.

But if you want it different text css depending on GET-parameters, then it can be implemented by means of php

Apache & PHP:

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   Header set Content-type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>
```

style.css:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: text/css')
...
```

---

or Nginx:

```
location /style.css {
    if ($args ~ "v=(\d+)") {
        rewrite ^(.*) style$1?.css redirect;
    }
}
```