# whats does the ?history=1 mean after a .js file?

Tags: javascript, css, browser-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does appending “?v=1” to CSS and Javascript URLs in link and script tags do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do)

I have seen some JS and CSS files carry this and not quite sure what it means or what its used for. In the Asual jQuery Address plugin you can add query strings to determine what options to switch on and off.

`someFile.js?history=1`

Comment: this means a failure to configure caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ensures that users have the latest version of a JS or CSS file in case an older version is cached by their browser.

Comment: I have seen some that have .js?history=1

Comment: @s2xi: It can also be used to pass a variable to the javascript, though it has to find its own `<script>` tag and read the `src` attribute first.

Comment: oh.. explain, what you mean. Do you have an example?

Comment: It could also be used to ask their servers for a specific version of the file. Just because it says someFile.js doesn't mean it directly grabs someFile.js. For example, may be a php script that responds whenever someone asks for someFile.js which would then process a specific version and THEN spit out a javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

This querystring value makes each new version of the file (be it javascript, css, or some other asset) unique so that the browser grabs the latest version, ignoring any previously cached version (and the browser won't have a cached version, since the URL is unique).