# Changing a footer background color isn't working when I edit main.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, colors

I'm trying to change the background color of a Wordpress site's footer. I used Chrome to "Inspect" the element and I saw that it was the `footer-top` class. So I went to Bluehost->File Manager and found the file, then I found 2 instances of the `footer-top` class. For both of them, I changed the color part to `#000000` (I want this color). But when I save the changes, the site doesn't update. Could someone help me troubleshoot?

**Strange note:** I found that the link to the `main.css` stylesheet is this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='css-main-css'  href='http://www.thefashban.com/wp-content/themes/akay/css/main.css?ver=4.7.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

...but what is that `?ver=4.7.1` part? I have a main.css file, but not one that ends in `?ver=4.7.1`. I see that the element is taking from a file with this at the end, but I can't find it.

Comment: Probably a browser cache issue. Clear browser cache and reload the page. Then check if it is updated.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`The ?ver=4.7.1` is use for caching. As long as that number does not change the browser will know your css has not been updated and will get it from cache instead of making a new request.

Here is a more complete answer : [Why adding version number to CSS file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671168/why-adding-version-number-to-css-file-path)

you could `disable cache` in your browser (in the network tab inside chrome developer tools for example) to make sure you are loading a fresh version of your file.