# Issue linking CSS files exported from Bootstrap Studio

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-studio

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. I designed my webpages in visual studio. At first, I just copied my HTML code into the .cshtml documents, and I moved the .css files to the appropriate locations (in wwwroot).

When I did so, at the end of the .css files, there was the following link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/styles.min.css?h=a9f290cd0cc57883e137369b4ae648cc">
```

I did not worry about the characters after the .css file extention at the time. The stylesheets worked with no issues.

After exporting again, I got new numbers at the end:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/styles.min.css?h=cd91b4591da6e3a842e0881e1a97d069">
```

I assumed this would be no problem, and that I could just replace the file. I replaced the file, and I replaced, the link. As result, all html pages associated with those stylesheets stopped working with the stylesheet. I checked the network, and it did seem that my browser was legitimately linking the stylesheet.

I reverted back to the original link, and the only styles missing were the new styles I added. It seems as though it is referencing an older stylesheet (which I cannot see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

As I expected, the numbers at the end were version numbers.

Workaround: when you export from Bootstrap Studio, there is a check box that determines whether or not to version the assets exported. It was previously checked. I simply unchecked it, and replaced the files and the corresponding links (to links that did not contain version numbers). Everything worked great.

I believe that the issue began in the bootstrap.css file with this line of code:

```
sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map
```

I also believe that the solution to this problem would be to replace the bootstrap.css.map file (which I apparently forgot to do) so that the version mapping will be updated.

If versioning is not desired, then one can do as I did, or they can comment out the line of code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671168/why-adding-version-number-to-css-file-path).