# Why does the CSS file not work in the Django project?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

When I shut down my PC and reopen my project every time I have to change the CSS file name to see the changes on the web. I have tried many ways to fix these issues.

*I have researched online but I did not find any answer on this.*

---

**I have tried  these ways to fix this error:**

- I have tried settings up `STATIC_ROOT=''`.
- I have tried setting up `STATICFILES_DIRS=[]`.

Please guide me to solve this error.

Comment: I don't think this is a Django specific problem. It's more of a browser cache problem. try using firefox browser and force reload (ctrl+f5 or ctrl+R in chrome)

Comment: checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671168/why-adding-version-number-to-css-file-path)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your pc is using the file stored in the cache.

You could do something like this to force update the file:

```
<link href="{% static 'custom/custom.css'%}?{% now 'U' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here you generate a unique timestamp every time when you update the page. This triggers a update of the file..