# Appending query string to all .js and .css files to prevent caching?

Tags: css, caching

Going thru a tutorial on building a web app and it has been recommended to ALWAYS append a query string "?v=1" to all .css and .js files to prevent caching.

Is this a 'best practice'?

Should the query string only be used during production-development?

Comment: why do you want to prevent caching? don't you want to make your app faster

Comment: A production site is the contrary of a development site. What is meant by "production-development"?

Comment: I work for a company and we develop a automobile site with massive traffic. We use Amazon S3 cloud for caching. For production environment you want it to cache specially if you have a lot of traffic

Comment: In production your JS/CSS (and all static content) should be cache-able with a far-future expires header. Best bet (and this requires a good architecture/design)... is to append the version number of the file to the filename (or query string (less ideal)) to ensure the cache is broken when the file is updated. e.g. `<script src="js/somefile_v1843.js"></script>` where "1843" is the version of that file

Comment: More detailed answer can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do

Comment: I think this the only good way to prevent caching, as mentioned in OP. [Prevent Your CSS and JavaScript Files From Being Cached](http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache) [Can We Prevent CSS Caching?](http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/) [How do you avoid caching during development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40667/how-do-you-avoid-caching-during-development)

Comment: prevent caching meaning, next time you release the code you increase the version number.  this way the browser will see it as a changed file reference and download the file again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is fine, but as far as best practice is concerned that is really subjective.

The most popular, most widely used CMS uses this method so I consider it the way to go.

What people don't understand is this method isn't the simplest way to signal to browsers that this file can be cached but is recached only when the version changes.

Short answer to the first question, **yes**.

As far as the second question "production-development" is an oxymoron. Which is it production or development?

Comment: The to answer the question, yes. Development should use the versioning for the same reasons production should.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something server-side, it's very easy to prevent caching for when your file changes:

PHP:

```
<script src="<?= $file.’?’.filemtime($file); ?>">
```

node.js

```
res.write('<script src="' + file + '?' + new Date(fs.statSync(file).mtime).getTime());
```

This appends the modified timestamp to the file, so it'll only prevent caching when the file has been modified.

Comment: I think you should also mention a way to make that file work, cause either you change the filename manually or you do something like this:
http://derek.io/blog/2009/auto-versioning-javascript-and-css-files/

Comment: That's what the question mark is for. Everything from the question mark onwards isn't part of the filename, it's the [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Generally, the server will just ignore it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. I was caught up with what I read in that link and when I stumbled upon your answer I skimmed it, and felt compelled to point it out. ;)