# Cache is not clearing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, browser, firebug

I have ASPX page with one JS file. JS file not updating in Firefox. I have cleared the cache of firefox.

Following are options tried but still getting old JS file: -

1. Tools->Clear Cache
2. Tools-> Options-> Advanced -> Cached Web Content -> Clear now.
3. Tools-> Clear Recent History.

Firefox Version : 13.0.1

Comment: is it clearing properly in other browsers?

Comment: add a query string to the end of your js file path in your aspx page

Comment: Why not try a complete clearing of all the data. Just goto history and clear all history from beginning of time. If that still dint help something else might be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl + R (hard refresh) and/or add a querystring to the js src, like:

```
<script src="scripts/myjavascript.js?v=1"></script>
```

More info on this technique:
[What does appending "?v=1" to CSS and Javascript URLs in link and script tags do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do)

Comment: CTRL+F5 to force cache purge CTRL+R just reload

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot seem to clear the cache you could try adding a query string onto the file path. As long as the querystring you add changes each time the page loads, by an increment or some kind of random generator, then the file will not be able to be retrieved from the cache. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
```

becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?randomstring">
```