# I Need to clear browser cache automatically when i move files to server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

When ever i move any css or any other files because of browser cache our client is displayed the old page and we need to inform them to clear their browser cache each time.Is there an easy solution to this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. one of the simplest is to append a version number to your links

ie

```
<link ... href="http://mysite/style.css?v=12">
```

Comment: so if i have 2 different css files and changed content in only one then do i need to change the version of that css link or any css link will work

Comment: because the query string is different the browser will not used the cached version. It doesnt affect the file which is requested

Comment: advanced users see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do

Comment: also explains why cache-control doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into HTTP Cache Headers?
From what I understand you can state if things get cached, get never cached, etc.
Those three headers are

Cache-Control, 
Last-Modified and 
Expires

Use "Cache-Control: no-cache" to completely prevent caching
or better yet use (eg) "Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 12:00:00 GMT"
and/or "Expires: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 12:00:00 GMT"

( from http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/caching/ )

Comment: it seems better to use the method described in Ewans comment ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do )