# What does ?_0_ mean when placed at the end of source path of a js file in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

What does ?*0* mean when placed at the end of source path of a js file in  tag? For example, in the following script tag, you will see the ?*0* appended to the end. What does it signify?

```
<script src="/xxx/xxx/xxx/header.js?_0_"></script>
```

Comment: Adding that kind of things is probably to force the browser to reload the js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does appending "?v=1" to CSS and Javascript URLs in link and script tags do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just basic versioning of the js file. It's a mechanism to prevent browser cache. If they build another header.js they will add `?_1_` behind it. This way the browser loads the new version.

Answer (score 3):

The `?_0_` might just be used as a cachebuster? Here is a post that talks about cachebusting (look at the query strings section): https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/