# How to see the webpage changes without clearing browser cache?

Tags: html, css

I have these HTML and CSS files both are perfectly linked with each other using the `<link>` tag. So what my problem is that I have a CSS code that I update later on for example I changed the color of the p tag into blue afterwards because I don't like the red color.

for example I changed:

```
p {
  color: red;
}
```

Into

```
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

but the color it still stays red like before after I reload the page and I don't know why, and If I open it in another browser window it surprisingly does show the changes meaning the text does show as blue instead of red,

but I want the changes to work on the previous browser window too as soon as I reload the webpage.

I suppose this is an issue related to browser cache and stuff but I wasn't able to find any good solutions online so here I am again asking this question on SO about how to get the changes without clearing the browser cache or opening an entirely new browser window.

I am not on an online webpage just testing something on my local environment.

Thanks for your precious time and solution in advance.

Comment: Just use `[ctrl] + [f5]` to circumvent the browser cache completely …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a browser related issue - usually pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> is the solution. This tells the browser that you think, there is a newer version of the website available and it ignores the cache and reloads the website.

Answer (score 1):

Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> button and it will reload but also re-install the css file of website again.

If it didn't work try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a version number like in this post: [What does appending "?v=1" to CSS and JavaScript URLs in link and script tags do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466989/what-does-appending-v-1-to-css-and-javascript-urls-in-link-and-script-tags-do)

This is needed since you can't tell the users to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> when you deploy a new version into production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It was quite helpful. and I will surely consider this in the future.