# One library for deflate, gzip, and zlib in .net

Tags: .net, compression, gzip, zlib, deflate

First, let's define some commonly confused terms:

```
deflate = compression_algorithm;
zlib = header + deflate + trailer;
gzip = header + deflate + trailer;
```

I'm looking for a library that will basically let me do the following:

```
if(method == "gzip"){
    Response.Filter = new CompressionLibrary.OutputStream(Response.Filter, CompressionLibrary.Formats.GZIP);
}
else if(method == "deflate"){
    Response.Filter = new CompressionLibrary.OutputStream(Response.Filter, CompressionLibrary.Formats.DEFLATE);
}
else if(method == "zlib"){
    Response.Filter = new CompressionLibrary.OutputStream(Response.Filter, CompressionLibrary.Formats.ZLIB);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to comparably test the 3 compression formats for use on the web. I would like for the deflate compression algorthims for each format to be the same exact implementation. I've already hacked away at zlib.net to force it to give me raw deflate on command (via an "undocumented feature")...however, adding the gzip header and trailer are little out of my league.

Anyone know of a .net library that does this?

---

**Clarification:**

HTTP 1.1's **deflate** compression *format* is actually the *zlib* compression format. Zlib is a wrapper around the deflate; it has a 2 byte header and a 4 byte trailer, **always** (when the compression methods and levels are identical).

**Gzip** uses the same compressed data format internally as zlib...which is deflate (raw deflate, not HTTP 1.1 deflate [which is zlib]). From my own preliminary testing, gzipped data is 11 out of 12 times larger than zlib.

**deflate** is a compression algorithm that is used to compress data. When there are no wrapper methods (e.g., headers or trailers) around deflated data, I call it "deflate" - perhaps I should have called it **"raw deflate"** instead.

I am doing an analysis of these compression methods and their support within web browsers and need to use a single compression method for all three types.

Comment: Do you mean "deflate" as the compression algorithm, or as the compression method?  Note that deflate==zlib if you're talking method (see: http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_faq.html#faq38 )  It's not clear to me if you have 3 cases to deal with, or 2.  In the latter case would System.IO.Compression classes work?

Comment: What are you trying to determine?  zlib is just an implementation of the deflate compression method (RFC 1951) and the gzip file format (RFC 1952).  It makes no sense to compare gzip and zlib.  Or are you trying to compare the .NET implementation of gzip and deflate with the zlib implementation of gzip and deflate?

Comment: I started with definitions because the terms are often confused. When referring to deflate I am NOT talking about HTTP 1.1 deflate (that would be the zlib format: http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq39). I'll clarify in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) does [RFC 1950 (ZLIB)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html), [RFC 1951 (DEFLATE)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951.html), and [RFC 1952 (GZIP)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1952.html). 
It uses the same underlying compression engine for all three.

DotNetZip also does ZIP files.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I just sent Cheeso a message on codeplex about a typo on the home page not realizing that you are Cheeso.   :-D    Have you seen my research on the subject [here](http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/)?

Comment: Also, can you verify that when using DotNetZip's DEFLATE compression method no checksums are calculated?

Comment: If you use the DeflateStream class, there is no CRC32 calculated. If you use GZipStream, then there is a CRC32 calculated. I can't recall if ZLIB requires a checksum or not, but from memory I think ZLIB requires an Adler32, which is calculated. And, No, I haven't seen your research. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my reading of the standards documents and the work I've done with zlib, the .NET gzip and deflate implementations, and several other compression packages for .NET, I've determined:

1) "raw deflate" is always smaller than what you call "HTTP 1.1 deflate", which is always smaller than gzip.  Assuming that you used the same library to generate all three.  That is, for any particular compression library, deflate < zlib < gzip.

2) The differences in size are very small.  The difference between deflate and zlib is usually just a few bytes.  The difference between deflate and gzip is, at most, a few dozen bytes.  This is true regardless of the file size.

3) Different deflate implementations have widely varying compression ratios and execution times.  The zlib implementation, for example, gives better compression and faster execution than the .NET 3.5 implementation.

4) Interoperability between the different implementations is almost 100%.  That is, a deflate (or gzip) file created by one library can be decompressed by any other library.  I have heard of cases where this is not true, but I was unable to construct one.

5) It takes significantly longer to create gzip than it does zlib, because of the CRC calculation.

I do not know of a C# library that allows you to generate a zlib or gzip file, given the raw deflate data, but you should be able to construct them fairly easily if you study the standards documents.

I also do not know of any browser that supports "raw deflate".  But then, I can't say that I've actually tried it.  I've always used the "HTTP 1.1 deflate".

Comment: thanks, this confirms everything I've been trying to promote. And, you actually use raw deflate, not HTTP 1.1 deflate (unless you don't like IE users so much that you won't send them inflatable data). :-)   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574168/deflate-compression-browser-compatibility-and-advantages-over-gzip) for details.

Comment: I find it very very very surprising that the CRC calculation makes a material difference in the time required for compression. DEFLATE is the underlying algorithm, and it uses Huffman coding plus LZ77. These are cpu intensive; in particular LZ77 searches through a sliding window for matches. CRC calculation requires an XOR, on the already-compressed data, which takes much much less time than the compression. CRC is not "free" but I believe it should be vanishingly small in comparison to the compression time, for any non-insignificant compression payload.

Comment: I'd like to see the code that reproduces the significant difference you described. One possibility is that when measuring compression in an HTTP server scenario, the server buffers data if it will be CRC'd, and does not buffer if no CRC is required. This may lead to a latency difference, but the cause would not be the CRC operation ?*per se*, but rather the buffering.

Comment: @Cheeso: I was pretty surprised by it, too, but my results were repeatable. I published them here:  http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=615. Understand, that was October 2007, using whichever .NET flavor was around at the time. I don't know what it'd be like today.