# why does IIS7 static/dynamic compression only work for 200 responses?

Tags: iis-7, compression, gzip

Why is IIS7.5 only performing static and dynamic compression when the response code is 200?

How do I make it compress all responses where the request had an appropriate `Accept-Encoding` header?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that the resource you are returning in a non HTTP 200 is not listed in the 'file extensions to compress' list?

Comment: nope. just make a blank aspx page, return 200 and it works, return anything else and it doesnt. Well, not 403, 404, 418, or 500 anyway.

Comment: Where are you specifying compressiong? Site level, or machine level?

Comment: default is `on` for all sites, at machine level. The site has no overrides, but even if i add it to the web config to force it as on, i get the same behaviour.

Comment: @Andrew we're wondering the same thing ourselves.

Comment: I reckon it's by design, and the IIS team simply took the wrong decision.

Comment: Don't use IIS's built-in compression anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574168/deflate-compression-browser-compatibility-and-advantages-over-gzip and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681516/one-library-for-deflate-gzip-and-zlib-in-net .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to answer the 2nd part of your question, How do I make it compress all responses where the request had an appropriate Accept-Encoding header?

You do it with HTTPModules.

Here is one way using [Ionic.Zlib](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). The module prefers to send RAW DEFLATE content because it is ALWAYS faster and ALWAYS smaller than than GZIP ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574168/deflate-compression-browser-compatibility-and-advantages-over-gzip)).

A more complete solution is now hosted on github https://github.com/davidmurdoch/DEFLATE-Compression-for-IIS .

Comment: excellent details, thanks for the links to the other questions

Comment: no problem. the code above was mostly copy/pasted from another source and I never realized how bag the actual code was...so, I'm working on making it better and will update this soon.

Comment: yeah no worries, i know how to do it myself (although thanks for the info on the zip lib). just couldnt understand why IIS was being strange, thought i was doing something wrong. seems not, its just poorly designed.

Comment: @Andrew, I put a little something together on github for this: https://github.com/davidmurdoch/DEFLATE-Compression-for-IIS