# Does changing scheme from gzip to deflate fix ie6 incompatibility?

Tags: iis, gzip, internet-explorer-6, deflate

Internet explorer 6 VS1 doesn't support gzip compression correctly.
It does however understand deflate.
Is it sufficient to change the scheme name in `applicationhost.config` from gzip to deflate to fix this issue?
Are there any downsides to using deflate instead of gzip?

```
<!-- c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config -->
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <!-- changed name="gzip" to name="deflate" -->
    <scheme name="deflate" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        [...]
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        [...]
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Related links:

- [Deflate compression browser compatibility and advantages over GZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574168/gzip-vs-deflate-zlib-revistited)
- http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690689(v=VS.90).aspx
- http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to solve the problem. Internet explorer 6 VS1 doesn't support gzip nor deflate. :-(

At least not when using dynamic compression on iis.