# When target stream emit error events, can we somehow reuse the source stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to achieve following error handling:

1. Say we have a `readable` stream.
2. We pipe it into a `transform` stream.
3. Somehow the `transform` stream emits an `error`.
4. We would like to recover the `readable` stream (and all of its data), and re-pipe it into another `transform` stream.

**Step 4 appears to be difficult**: I can listen to `unpipe` event on the target stream (`transform` stream) and retrieve a reference to the source stream (`readable` stream), but at least some chunks of its data have been lost.

**Can we do this without creating a custom transform stream?**

A real-world example is `deflate` content encoding, [where in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519828/how-can-we-distinguish-deflate-stream-from-deflateraw-stream), you need `zlib.createInflateRaw()` instead of `zlib.createInflate()`, but we can't decide which one would be the correct choice before looking at the response body buffers.

Comment: Don't most sites support gzip these days anyway? Just send `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in your request and you don't have to worry about any deflate issues.

Comment: @mscdex you are right but for a http library we can't ignore those old and crazy deflate-only servers, I ended up doing this, seems like the best I can do at the moment. https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/master/index.js#L209-L222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to introduce a stream in the middle just to read the first byte. For example:

```
(function readChunk() {
  var chunk = res.read();
  if (!chunk)
    return res.once('readable', readChunk);

  var inflate;
  if ((chunk[0] & 0x0F) === 0x08)
    inflate = zlib.createInflate();
  else
    inflate = zlib.createInflateRaw();

  // Put chunk back into stream
  res.unshift(chunk);

  // Prepare the decompression
  res.pipe(inflate);

  output = new Response(inflate, response_options);
  resolve(output);
})();
```

Also, `var body = res.pipe(new stream.PassThrough());` is unnecessary, you can just use `res` where appropriate.