# Data compressed in Swift 5 on macOS/iPhone cannot be decompressed by anything else

Tags: ios, swift, linux, macos, zlib

I am trying to decompress some JSON (representing a `Codable` type) that was compressed on an iPhone, using the `NSData` instance method [`.compressed(using: .zlib)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/3174960-compressed). Note `.zlib` is the [format recommended by Apple for portability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/compressionalgorithm/zlib).

The output bytes are not recognized by tools like Python 3's `zlib` library (on macOS 12.2 or Ubuntu Linux 21.10) or the command-line `uncompress` (on macOS).

***Question:*** how can I decompress this data on other devices/not in Swift on Apple?

Here's a basic example which can be thrown into `compressor.swift` and compiled/run to produce the compressed data, following [this guide](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-compress-and-decompress-data)

```swift
import Foundation

struct SomeThing: Codable {
  var thing: String
  
  init(thing: String) {
    self.thing = thing
  }
}

let thing = SomeThing(thing: "abc")

let encoder = JSONEncoder()

let encodedThing = try encoder.encode(thing)

let compressedEncodedThing = try (encodedThing as NSData).compressed(using: .zlib)

try compressedEncodedThing.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/somewhere/abc.Z"),
                                 options: [])
```

Compiling and running that on macOS produces `abc.Z` as expected.

This code will decompress the file we just wrote, so long as we compile on macOS:

```
import Foundation

let readBytes = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/somewhere/abc.Z"))

let decompressed = try! (readBytes as NSData).decompressed(using: .zlib) as Data

let decompString = String(decoding: decompressed, as: UTF8.self)

print(decompString) // prints {"thing": "abc"}
```

Trying the same thing on Linux (Ubuntu 21.10 with Swift 5.5.3 Release toolchain),

```
$ swiftc decompressor.swift 
decompressor.swift:5:47: error: value of type 'NSData' has no member 'decompressed'
let decompressed = try! (readBytes as NSData).decompressed(using: .zlib) as Data
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~
decompressor.swift:5:68: error: cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'zlib'
let decompressed = try! (readBytes as NSData).decompressed(using: .zlib) as Data
```

which suggests that the open sourced `NSData` lacks some methods it has on Apple hardware/OS.

Other things I've tried that strongly suggest true ZLib encoding is not being used:

- Calling

  ```sh
  uncompress abc.Z
  ```

  (from the same macOS computer that produced `abc.Z`) returns

  ```
  uncompress: abc.Z: Inappropriate file type or format
  ```

  I've also tried using `gunzip`, to similar failure message.
- Tried `zlib.decompress` in Python 3. The Python failure is perhaps the most informative: this script crashes with error  `error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

  ```py
  import zlib

  with open("/path/to/somewhere/abc.Z", "rb") as f:
      bytesRead = f.read()

  decompressed = zlib.decompress(bytesRead)

  print(decompressed)
  ```
- The first 20 bytes of the file, in hexadecimal, are:

  ```
  $ od -x -N 20 abc.Z
  0000000  56ab  c92a    ccc8    574b    52b2    4c4a    564a    05aa
  0000020  0000                                                        
  0000021
  ```

Comment: Please provide the first 20 bytes or so in hexadecimal.

Comment: I added the bytes.

Comment: decompressed is not native Swift. It is a Foundation method.

Comment: That's right, you have to `import Foundation` to get access on macOS, too. (My Swift examples all start with that.) But it seems to not get the same library on Linux. Maybe I've not configured something right, but it was a fresh download of 5.5.3 release so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data appears to be a raw deflate stream. In python you can try `zlib.decompress(bytesRead, wbits=-15)`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help. For others stumbling across this, this was interesting follow-up reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519828/how-can-we-distinguish-deflate-stream-from-deflateraw-stream