# Handling HTTP ContentEncoding "deflate"

Tags: java, http, http-compression, content-encoding

What **InputStream** type should be used to handle URLConnection streams that have HTTP **Content-Encoding** set to **deflate**?

For a Content-Encoding of gzip or zip I use a GZIPInputStream, no problem.

For a Content-Encoding  of "deflate" I have tried using **InflaterInputStream** and **DeflaterInputStream** but I get

> java.util.zip.ZipException: unknown
>   compression method
>           at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:147)

My understanding is that "deflate" encoding refers to **Zlib** compression, and according to the [docs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) this should be handled by InflaterInputStream.

Comment: God I encounter the same situation. Raw deflate doesn't have one header so there is No way getting to know what it is. I thought my code is incorrect and check and check and check... damn. After this I have suggested the archive manager I'm using to support decoding raw deflate data so I can just try to open it with the archive manager and I'll know "Oh! My code is good! And this is deflate!".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In HTTP/1.1, `Content-encoding: deflate` actually refers to the DEFLATE compression algorithm, as defined by [RFC 1951](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951.html), wrapped in the zlib data format, as defined by [RFC 1950](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html).

However some vendors just implement the DEFLATE algorithm as defined RFC 1951, completely ignoring RFC 1950 (no zlib headers).

Others have been hit by the same issue:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/www-talk@w3.org/msg01000.html
- [Internet Explorer 8 + Deflate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077869/internet-explorer-8-deflate/2541174#2541174)

In order to work around this, try to instantiate the `InflaterInputStream` passing an `Inflater` that was created with the `nowrap` parameter set to `true`:

```
in = new InflaterInputStream(conn.getInputStream()), new Inflater(true));
```

Comment: Both RFCs seem to reference Zlib, but I guess different versions?

Comment: "6.2.2.2 Deflate Coding

The "deflate" format is defined as the "deflate" compression mechanism (described in [RFC1951]) used inside the "zlib" data format ([RFC1950]).

Note: Some incorrect implementations send the "deflate" compressed data without the zlib wrapper." -- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-11.html#rfc.section.6.2.2.2

Comment: RFCs make excellent example of how to write confusing, misleading technical documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, using the InflaterInputStream with an Inflater object did not always produce the correct decompression. I had to detect the headers and tell the Inflater where the offset to the payload was.

http://thushw.blogspot.com/2014/05/decoding-html-pages-with-content.html