# Which InputStream should I use if server reponse is content-encoding 'deflate'

Tags: java, http, inputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling HTTP ContentEncoding “deflate”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932117/handling-http-contentencoding-deflate)

HTTP Request:

`Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate`

HTTP Response:

`Content-Encoding:deflate`

And programming language is java.

Comment: Show the code you use for connecting and getting the input stream

Comment: Please check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932117/handling-http-contentencoding-deflate

Comment: @Will that's cool! it works!!