# HTTP Request parse the data Content-Encoding "deflate"

Tags: java, rest, http-compression

I am receiving the request in my Rest API with headers as "Content-Encoding" as deflate.
How to parse the request and make it a String in Java?

Please share any code reference to do the same.

headers: 'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate',
'Content-Encoding': 'deflate'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling HTTP ContentEncoding "deflate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932117/handling-http-contentencoding-deflate)

Comment: BTW, while you _could_ handle this yourself, it's more common to a pub web server, such as Nginx or Apache in front of the app as a reverse proxy, and let the proxy handle it.

Comment: Does your REST framework not handle this already?  What behavior are you seeing that indicates a problem?