# does gzip and deflate compression give the same payload

Tags: compression

According to wiki the compressed data in deflate and gzip are the same. the only difference is the header and footer ? In gzip the footer seems to have a checksum and a file compressed with deflate does not have such a item.

could someone please shed some light upon this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [gzip = deflate + checksum + header + footer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388633/139010).

Lots more reading, if you care: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gzip+vs+deflate.

Comment: gzip = header + raw deflate + footer, where the footer contains a check value.

Answer (score 1):

You have not stated the context of your question, but I am going to hazard a guess that you mean HTTP content encoding.  In that case "deflate" actually means the zlib format, which is a raw deflate stream with a two-byte header and four-byte trailer, where the trailer is an Adler-32 checksum value.  gzip is also a raw deflate stream with a header and a trailer, but they are different and larger.  The gzip header is at least ten bytes, and may be more if there is a file name and/or extra field.  The gzip trailer is eight bytes, consisting of a CRC-32 check value and the uncompressed length modulo 2^32.

You can find the raw deflate compressed data format defined in [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).  You can find the zlib header and trailer defined in [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950), and the gzip header and trailer defined in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).