# MySQL overhead on local server

Tags: php, mysql, json, wamp

I have a mobile app running built with JQuery mobile, and response times are very important to me, as I want to provide a smooth experience for my users.

I just moved the installation of the website to a local server, to increase performance of the app, as it connects to a local web server, instead of a hosted one.

I installed WAMP on a networked computer (newest version), but for some reason, the result being sent to me via my local MySQL server, is much bigger than that of the previous hosted one. If I run the exact same query/output on my local server, as on the hosted one, the output size varies greatly.

For example; I'm generation an output and encode it with JSON, for use in JQuery. The result spit out by my hosted web server is 1kb but the same on my local server is 6kb. This in turn leads to a much greater response time (100-200ms vs 1-1.5sec).

As I said, it's a fresh installation of WAMP, and the computer it runs on is idle at 0% CPU use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is the actual content different? If not, you may want to look at your Apache settings, namely compression.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856879/675934