# How can I compress the response of an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, optimization

I return the whole HTML as the response of an ajax request *(not just an array as JSON)*. So as you know, the response will be larger a bit *(than JSON)*. Because it contains some more things like html tags, html attributes etc ... So to

- tncreased scalability (reduced server load).
- Less network bandwidth (lower cost).
- Better user experience (faster).

I want to compress the response. Something like `.gzip` format. Based on so tests, this is the size of an ajax response:

[image]

And this is the size of an ajax response which is zipped:

[image]

See? There is a huge different between them in theirs sizes.

---

All I want to know, is it possible to compress the response of an ajax request on the way and convert it to a regular text on the client side? For doing that do I need to do some changes in the web service *(like nginx)* configuration? Or it does that automatically?

Comment: Did you [enable gzip compression in Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html) already?

Comment: @LarsBeck If I do so, then all ajax responses will be gzip automatically?

Comment: Nginx will compress almost anything https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/

Answer (score 0):

You should use Lz-string method to compress data and send using ajax call and at the time of response, again use it by decompressing it

GITHUB links : https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/

Documentation & usage : https://coderwall.com/p/mekopw/jsonc-compress-your-json-data-up-to-80

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out some of the other StackOverflow posts, plus Wikipedia links & articles on the web regarding Deflate & Gzip. Here are some links for you to peruse. They have some interesting charts & information in them:

1. [StackOverflow: Why Use Deflate Instead of Gzip for Text Files Served by Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388595/why-use-deflate-instead-of-gzip-for-text-files-served-by-apache)
2. [StackOverflow: Is There Any Performance Hit Involved In Choosing Gzip Over Deflate For-
   HTTP.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211284/is-there-any-performance-hit-involved-in-choosing-gzip-over-deflate-for-http-com)
3. [Wikpedia: Deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)
4. [Wikipedia: Gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)
5. [Article: How to Optimize Your Site with GZip Compression](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)
6. [RFC: Deflate](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-deflate.html)